# Cannot cast an Object to generic without a warning

Tags: java, generics

I've got a class defined like this:

```
public class SizeCache<T extends Identifiable> implements Observer {}
```

Identifiable is just an interface that defines a couple of methods.

I have a method:

```
public T put(final T item) {}
```

That adds an item to a list and is usually called directly with an item of type T but can come from an Observer so in my Observer I want to ensure it is of type T.

However, I cannot write this:

```
public void update(Observable observable, Object data) {
if (data instanceof T) {}
}
```

As it tells me I need to use its erasure Identifiable.

However, when I cast it to Identifiable

```
Identifiable dataItem = (Identifiable) data;
```

the call to put(dataItem) fails with the method put(T) is not applicable for the arguments.

and if I cast to the real type T

```
T dataItem = (T) data;
```

It warns me it's an unchecked cast. How do I fix this?

Comment: You have to accept the unchecked cast, basically. Either that, or take a `Class<T>` as a parameter to the constructor, so you can perform the cast safely.

Comment: Why doesn't the signature of `update` accept a `T` instead of `Object`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no getting around the fact that it's an unchecked cast.  Java cannot check at runtime whether it's a `T` because of type erasure.

One way to provide a runtime check is to have a `Class<T>` available to your `update` method.  Your observer could take a `Class<T>` in a constructor and you can store it for later use by `update`.  Then you can call [`isInstance`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isInstance%28java.lang.Object%29):

```
if (clazz.isInstance(data))
```

You'll still have to cast to `T`, but since you're now ensuring type safety with this check, you can suppress the warning with the `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` annotation on your `update` method.

Comment: Thanks, I just assumed I was doing something wrong. I don't like the idea of passing in an object just as a hack :(, I'll put a try block around it instead just in case.

Comment: Use type.isAssignableFrom(object.getClass()) instead.

Comment: @ike_love That will work too, but we already have the object; there is no need to call `getClass()` when `isInstance` will work directly on the object itself.  The `isAssignableFrom` method is best used when you have the `Class` object but not the object itself.

Comment: @ike_love Your linked post explains how `clazz.instanceOf(data)` is equivalent to `class.isAssignableFrom(data.getClass())`.  It doesn't explain why you think `isAssignableFrom` is preferable when you already have an instance of the class.

Comment: if you already have `clazz` of type `Class<T>`, then you would not need to do an unchecked cast to `T` -- instead, you can just do `clazz.cast(data)` to get an expression of type `T`.

Comment: @newacct I had forgotten about that method; that's good to know.

Answer (score 1):

There are some cases when you can't get away without a warning.
In your case if you are absolutely sure that you'll receive an object of type `T` you can suppress the warning like this:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
```

If you want to check for the runtime type you will need a `Class<T>` object in your class and compare that to the input `data` like this:

```
dataClass.isInstance(data);
```

Just make sure that you have `dataClass` on the left side of the statement because `isInstance` will check for `null` values but if `data` is null you'll get a `NullPointerException`.

Answer (score 0):

Due to type erasure, the runtime does not keep track of the actual type arguments you used to create an object. You can however, keep track of this information yourself by passing the `Class` object for T to the constructor of your generic type, and the use that class object for instanceof and casting:

```
public class SizeCache<T extends Identifiable> implements Observer {
    private final Class<T> tClass;

    public SizeCache(Class<T> tClass) {
        this.tClass = tClass;
    }

    public void update(Observable observable, Object data) {
        if (tClass.isInstance(data)) {
            put(tClass.cast(data));
        }
    }
}
```